# sound won't change note and keeps running javascript

Tags: javascript, audio

I'm trying to get to play a  ist of notes based on the frequencies involved with optional switching to another waveform, when ever i try this i can only get it to make one note rather than while loop through the notes. Any ideas as to how i can improove?

```
<script>
function play_tune(frequencies, oscillator_types){
var context = new AudioContext();
if (typeof oscillator_types == 'undefined'){
oscillator_types = ['sine'];
}
if (typeof oscillator_types_index == 'undefined'){
oscillator_types_index = 0;
}
var oscillator = context.createOscillator();
frequencies_index = 0
while (frequencies_index != frequencies.length){
if (oscillator_types_index >= oscillator_types.length){
oscillator_types_index = 0;
}
oscillator.type = oscillator_types[oscillator_types_index];
oscillator.frequency.value = frequencies[frequencies_index];
oscillator.connect(context.destination);
oscillator.start();
wait(1);
oscillator.stop();
oscillator_types_index = oscillator_types_index + 1;
frequencies_index = frequencies_index + 1;
}
}
play_tune([250, 200, 500, 1000, 1500, 350, 460, 720, 2000])
</script>
```

Ive tried changing the lines around, checking the interent, setting the timer to zero whcih produces no audible sound at all, ive tried using time-out() but that just makes all the notes play at once. I was rather hoping that a while loop through notes, with a wait for each note to finish would enable multiple notes to play

Comment: This might help - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Simple_synth

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running everything in a `while` loop and blocking, use `setTimeout` to trigger playing the next frequency.  Something like:

```js
var context = new AudioContext();
var oscillator = context.createOscillator();
oscillator.type = 'sine'
oscillator.connect(context.destination);

var frequencies_index = 0;
var frequencies = [250, 200, 500, 1000, 1500, 350, 460, 720, 2000]

// Start playing tones
play_tune(frequencies_index)

function play_tune(index) {
  frequencies_index = index

  // Start playing the first tone
  if (index === 0) {
    oscillator.frequency.setValueAtTime(frequencies[index], context.currentTime)
    oscillator.start()
  }

  // Stop playing after the last tone
  else if (index === frequencies.length) {
    oscillator.stop()
    return
  }

  // Play the frequency
  else {
    oscillator.frequency.setValueAtTime(frequencies[index], context.currentTime)
  }
  
  // Play next tone after 1 second
  setTimeout(() => play_tune(frequencies_index + 1), 1000);
}
```

You can easily add the ability to switch oscillator types at each note trigger.